# C++: Could polymorphic member remains the same?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have a class that has a member that is an instance of another class that has a vector as member; like here:

```
class C1
{
private:
  std::vector<int> m_intVec;
  // ...
};
```

and

```
class C2 : public I1 // this is an interface
{
private:
  C1 m_c1;
  // ...
public:
  void getC1(C1& c1Out) const
  {
    c1Out = m_c1
  }
};
```

The interface looks like this:

```
class I1
{
public:
  virtual ~I1() {}
  virtual void getC1(C1& c1Out) const = 0;
};
```

I call the C2 class using polymorphism:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  // ...
  I1* i1 = new C2;
  // ...
  while (1)
  {
    // set the member c1 // this is not happening all the time
    // ...
    C1 c1Obj; 
    i1->getC1(c1Obj);
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

My questions here are: Could `c1Obj` have the value in the previous iteration? (in other words: Can the `i1`'s member have the same value as previous iteration, if it was not reset?) If yes, can someone explain it to me why? any ideas how to fix this?

If the answer is no, why for some cases I get the same results:  I am blurring a region in images, and in some cases the blurred region is the same as previous, and I do not know if it is a bug, or not.

Comment: As written, this is invalid : `I1 i1 = new C2;`. I'm sure you meant that to be `I1* i1 = new C2;`, right?

Comment: @WhozCraig Or, even better, `I1 i1;`.

Comment: `c1Obj` is constructed *and* destroyed during each iteration. What problem are you *really* trying to solve?

Comment: what is not happening?

Comment: I have edited it: I have the same region in an image and i do not know if it is a bug or not...

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What exactly are you observing? What exactly about your observations puzzles you? That asked, I'd be amazed if c1Obj would not have the same value in each iteration, after getC1(). After all, it's always the same object which gets assigned to it.

Comment: in other words: Can the `i1`'s member have the same value as previous iteration, if it was not reset?

Comment: @Jarod42: In code there is a virtual destructor, I have just forgotten to add it here

Comment: @thedarksideofthemoon Please, always, make copy-paste. By introducing such mistakes when you paraphrase code you mislead those who try to answer your question. The example code you provide should be complete, compiling and reproduce your original problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO**, this is not possible.  `c1Obj` is guaranteed to be created each time in the loop, and destroyed once the loop scope ends.  You are doing it wrong:

```
I1 i1 = new C2;
```

should be

```
I1* i1 = new C2;
```

and

```
 i1.getC1(c1Obj);
```

should be

```
 i1->getC1(c1Obj);
```

**Note:**
`i1` (actually `c2`) will contain same `m_c1` object, so ater `i1->getC1(c1Obj);` statement, `c1Obj` will be always same.

Comment: Yes, those are some errors because I have not really copy-pate the code. I will correct it

Comment: the note explained it to me, otherwise, it is not answering my question. Thanks